# Scanner failing at the very end of the input file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have the following code:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("in.txt"));

    while(in.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(in.nextLine());
        System.out.println(in.nextLine());
        System.out.println(in.nextDouble());
        System.out.println(in.nextDouble());
        System.out.println(in.nextDouble());

        System.out.println(in.nextLine());
    }
```

Where in.txt is formatted as:

```
One Name
Second Name
double
double
double
One Name
Second Name
double
double
double
...
```

However, the while loop fails on the very last line in the input file. It prints the entire input file, but when it's done I get an error that says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
    at start.Start.main(Start.java:22)
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hasNext()` method must be called every time before a reading because, in case of true, this method can guarantee that there is at least one more element to read.  Your reading should look like this:

```
    if (in.hasNext())
        System.out.println(in.nextLine());
    if (in.hasNext())
        System.out.println(in.nextLine());
    if (in.hasNext())
        System.out.println(in.nextDouble());
    if (in.hasNext())
        System.out.println(in.nextDouble());
    if (in.hasNext())
        System.out.println(in.nextDouble());

    if (in.hasNext())
        System.out.println(in.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your Input file the pattern is:

```
One Name
Second Name
double
double
double
```

so your while loop must match this pattern in order to read the file as

```
while(in.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(in.nextLine());
    System.out.println(in.nextLine());
    System.out.println(in.nextDouble());
    System.out.println(in.nextDouble());
    System.out.println(in.nextDouble());
}
```

For better handling of unusual cases you should use proper hasNextXXX() method before reading every line as suggested by @rendon.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That extra call to `nextLine` that the OP has is to deal with the trailing newline after the third double; leaving it out would actually be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

rewrite your code as follows, it will print all values

```
while(in.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(in.nextLine());
    }
```